# Executing Commands from Windows on Unix via Batchfile

Tags: bash, batch-file, unix, ssh

I have a problem that cannot find a solution for quite a while.
I want to execute following line from a Batch file on my windows machine:

**ssh %1@%2 "D: && ssh %3@%4 cd /media/usbmsd/ && cp "$(ls -t /media/usbmsd | head -1)" /buffer"**

THis batch file will be later executed from a cmd line with the parameters. I am trying to access one system (windows) via ssh and that hop again via ssh to the another system(unix) and there I need to find the newest file in the /media/usbmsd directory and copy it to the folder buffer.

When I excetuting it from my cmd line i am getting following error:

**'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I have to say that I am not very experienced with this kind of application and am happy about any help

Greeting Denis

Comment: I am trying to change to the D: first... than access the other system (unix) via ssh ... there change to the folder /media/usbmsd/ and find there the newst file (first entry of the ls -t command) this file will be then copied to the directory "buffer"

Comment: Your quotes can't work, because the second quote (after cp) will stop the quoting.

Comment: I see it now. I have tried to make the commands simpler to get around the quotation marks:
ssh %1@%2 ssh %3@%4 cp "$(ls -t /media/usbmsd | head -1)" /buffer
still giving me the same error

Comment: From Windows you want to   ssh to unix system a, and then ssh from unix system a to unix system b and then copy the newest file in the /media/usbmsd to unix systemb b's /buffer directory?

The pipe in "| head" is being interpreted by windows and not the remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could connect via a proxy jump, then you don't need a second ssh command.
Then a bit obscure escaping of the quotes is necessary.
(I tested this without the intermediate windows client)
The first caret `^` is necessary to quote from the `cp` command, the backslashes are necessary to convince the first expansion to leave the quotes untouched.

```
ssh %3@%4 -o ProxyJump %1@%2 ^"cd /media/usbmsd/ && cp \"$(ls -t /media/usbmsd | head -1)\" /buffer'
```

But it should be much easier to place a script on the destination host **mycopyscript.sh**

```
cd /media/usbmsd/ && cp "$(ls -t /media/usbmsd | head -1)" /buffer
```

And then use:

```
ssh %3@%4 -o ProxyJump %1@%2 "./mycopyscript.sh"
```

Comment: It is giving me the error: command-line line 0: Missing argument.

Comment: @DenisFriedrich That's probably an error from your intermediate windows client. But you should examine each step separately, like testing first if this connect successfully to your destination ` ssh %3@%4 -o ProxyJump %1@%2`. Then test from your intermediate windows client the command

Comment: Okay that a good idea. I will tr y it step by sep